# Who was the real beginner of Lord Ganesha festival?

Tags: india, cultural-history, ancient-india, war, festival

**Introduction**

Ganesha is one of the most well-known and loved gods in Hinduism and is admired by most members of a Hindu family. Ganesh Chaturthi, one of the most popular festivals in India brings people from all caste, religion and creed together. The 10-days festival is celebrated usually in August or September depending on the Hindu calendar.

**Celebration Places**

Though this festival is celebrated across India, the states like Maharashtra, Tamil Nadu, Kerala and Goa are the top states for celebrating this festival with big enthusiasm. With Indians residing in every corner of the world, this festival is more like international now. So, we take you to the countries, apart from India, where you can enjoy this festival of love, happiness, celebrations, colours and festive dishes. Countries like Canada, Mauritius, Thailand, Singapore, Cambodia, Burma, US, UK and Fiji celebrate this festival and many of mentioned countries’ government have declared a public holiday for that day.

**Current Contradiction**

There are many contradictions going on in Pune city, Maharashtra state, India about the issue of a person who has started the Lord Ganesha festival in order to gather the people for better purpose.

I want to know - who is a real person behind the process of starting Lord Ganesha festival? I mean really the Indian Freedom Fighter "Lokmanya Tilak" or "Bhausaheb Laxman Jawale"?

In history, It has been written as 'Lokmanya Tilak' but now since 2 years, few people are saying that the real beginner of this festival is not he but someone other.

**Citations**

The required citations are,

1) The Lord Ganesha Festival -- 
[Ganesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesh_Chaturthi), [Link-2](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/history-and-origin-of-ganesh-chaturthi-festival)

2) Freedom Fighter 'Lokmanya Tilak' -- [Tilak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bal_Gangadhar_Tilak), [Link-2](https://www.mid-day.com/articles/a-look-in-history-at-how-ganesh-chaturthi-originated/17588181), [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MXkePP-Oiw)

3) News about contradiction - [News Paper link](https://indianexpress.com/article/cities/pune/pune-row-over-history-of-community-ganesh-festival-4752814/), [Link-2](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/pune/tilak-founder-of-public-ganeshotsav-fadnavis/articleshow/60039768.cms), [Deccan Herald News](https://www.deccanherald.com/content/628982/a-challenge-tilaks-claim-over.html)

Comment: The anonymous historian refers to documents from the 1890s which might answer the question. Have you looked at newspapers such as Dīnabandhu and Kesarī?

Comment: @AaronBrick, No.

Comment: @AaronBrick, I think, These newspapers are difficult to get.

Comment: @AaronBrick, I have got first copy of 'Kesari' newspaper published on 4th January 1881 and in Hindi language. But, it does not include anything about `Ganesh festival`

Comment: Yes, I'd expect you to have to go a library to see the issues from August or September 1892 and 1893. This is just one avenue of possible research.

Comment: @AaronBrick, I am thinking that Why would 'Lokmanya Tilak' write in his Kesari newspaper about "Bhausaheb Laxman Jawale" i.e. he is the beginner of this festival.

Comment: @AaronBrick, and nobody knows about 'Dīnabandhu' newspaper. I also heard this name first time.

Comment: @AaronBrick, 'Kesari' was very famous name. It is totally impossible to get newspaper of 1892 or 1893.

Comment: At what basis few people are saying about  "Bhausaheb Laxman Jawale" that I don't know. Or to oppose 'Lokmanya Tilak' as a beginner on his cast basis that may be possible. Many years before, Brahmin cast people dominated the other lower cast people. So, in order to take revenge on that, these people are making the statement about"Bhausaheb Laxman Jawale"...that may be possible.

Comment: If the question is solely about celebrations in Pune, please edit it to make that clear. Otherwise you have @DavePhD's answer below establishing that the festival in general is much older.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer, but since I see dates like 1892 being discussed in the OP links and comments I just want to point out some significantly earlier references.

The 1867 article "Tomtom Beaters, India" on page 431 of [Frank Leslie's Pleasant Hours volume III](https://books.google.com/books?id=bM0RAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA431&dq=Ganesh%20Chaturthi&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia56C82fLeAhWKwFkKHaMmCT0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Ganesh%20Chaturthi&f=false) discusses witnessing the "festival of Ganesh Chaturthi" on August 25th 1865 in Bombay.

Also the 1838 [The Connexion of the East-India Company's Government with the Superstitious and Idolatrous Customs and Rites of the Natives of India](https://books.google.com/books?id=gGDHn-jIUCkC&pg=PA88&dq=Vinayaka%20Chaturthi&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivtfKM1_LeAhUHn1MKHRZDC9wQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=Vinayaka%20Chaturthi&f=false) discusses Vinayaka Chaturthi in great detail on pages 88-92

See also the 1841 [A memoir of Mrs. Margaret Wilson](https://books.google.com/books?id=x-sDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA181&dq=%22Ganesha%20Chaturthi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr-qnv4PLeAhVntlkKHdZeA5kQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Ganesha%20Chaturthi%22&f=false), in the September 2nd, 1829 entry, writing from Harnai, where it is stated "The annual festival of Ganesha, which  is more devoutly celebrated here than in any other part of India..." and there is further discussion in the text and a footnote at page 181.